# Retrieve members of nested Outlook distribution list with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to retrieve the members of an Outlook distribution list. Most of them just contain contacts. However, strangely, I found some of these to contain themselves. When double-clicking on these in Outlook, I can see their members, but I couldn't figure out a possibility to access these in VBA.

The following code prints all members from all distribution lists in my local contact list, but, as I mentioned, for some distribution lists, it will only print themselves.

A sample result would look like this:
PDL - sampleList
PDL - sampleList -- sampleList@company.com

```
Sub test()

Dim objDistList As DistListItem

Const olFolderContacts = 10

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set colContacts = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items
intCount = colContacts.Count

For i = 1 To intCount
    If TypeName(colContacts.Item(i)) = "DistListItem" Then
        Set objDistList = colContacts.Item(i)
        Debug.Print objDistList.DLName
        For j = 1 To objDistList.MemberCount
    Debug.Print objDistList.GetMember(j).Name & " -- " & objDistList.GetMember(j).Address
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Kindly refer to my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645352/how-to-extract-the-members-info-of-a-distribution-list-and-save-in-outlook-con/77736266#77736266

Answer (score 0):

What about checking whether the Recipient.DisplayType returned from GetMember is of type OlDisplayType.olPrivateDistList?  Then you'd know to parse that as an embedded DL within the DL.