# How to extract the members' info of a distribution list, and save in Outlook contacts folder?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel VBA macro **(Macro A)** to export the members' information (Name and Address) from Outlook contacts folder to Excel.

I am trying to retrieve the members of a distribution list, and push them into my Outlook contacts folder on a daily basis. In that case, I can use **macro A** to export the latest DL members found in my contacts folder.

My ultimate objective is to get the latest name and email address of the members found in a distribution list in Excel format.

I searched online for solutions that can directly export the members of Outlook distribution list to Excel, but didn't achieve my intended effect.

```vb
Sub PrintDistListDetails()

    Dim olApplication As Object
    Dim olNamespace As Object
    Dim olContactFolder As Object
    Dim olDistListItem As Object
    Dim destWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim distListName As String
    Dim memberCount As Long
    Dim memberIndex As Long
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    
    Const olFolderContacts As Long = 10
    
    distListName = "dl.xxxxxx" 'change the name accordingly

    Set olApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNamespace = olApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olContactFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    Set olDistListItem = olContactFolder.Items(distListName)
    
    Set destWorksheet = Worksheets.Add

    destWorksheet.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Name", "Address") 'column headers
    
    memberCount = olDistListItem.memberCount
    
    rowIndex = 2 'start the list at Row 2
    'For memberIndex = 1 To memberCount
    For memberIndex = 1 To 1
        With olDistListItem.GetMember(memberIndex)
            destWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "a").Value = .Name
            destWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "b").Value = .Address
        End With
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next memberIndex
    
    destWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit
    
    Set olApplication = Nothing
    Set olNamespace = Nothing
    Set olContactFolder = Nothing
    Set olDistListItem = Nothing
    Set destWorksheet = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

It is only printing out the name of a distribution list, and its "parent email". For example, the output will be "dl.xxxxxx" in A2 cell, and "dl.xxxxxx@outlook.com" in B2 cell, instead of retrieving all the members in the distribution list.

How do I get the latest name and address of the members in a distribution list, and print in Excel using any of the two methods described above?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop only runs once:

```
For memberIndex = 1 To 1
```

change it back to

```
For memberIndex = 1 To memberCount
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed it back but the output is still the same regardless. Only the dl name and dl email address will appear instead of the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the contact folder is My contacts in "Set olContactFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)". It is not getting the members from the exchange server. We can try to add the distribution list into the email recipients and then get the members from the exchange server. There may be sub distribution lists in the primary distribution list. I only added to the 5th level/layer of the distribution list. But it can be expanded easily onwards. You can try below code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetUserEmailsFromDistList()
'Get the individual user email address from the distribution list provided

Dim myDistListName As String
Dim myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myDistListMembers As Outlook.AddressEntries

myDistListName = "My Primary Distribution List Name"
Set myMailItem = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set myRecipient = myMailItem.Recipients.Add(myDistListName)

Set myDistListMembers = myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList.Members
Call Expand1stLevelDistList(myDistListMembers)

End Sub


Sub Expand1stLevelDistList(myDistListMembers As Outlook.AddressEntries)
'Get email addresses from the 1st level/layer of the primary distribution list

Dim myDistListMemberItem As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To myDistListMembers.Count
    Set myDistListMemberItem = myDistListMembers.Item(i)
    If myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olUser Then
        Debug.Print "Level 1" & vbTab & i & vbTab & myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    ElseIf myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olDistList Then
        Call Expand2ndLevelDistList(myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeDistributionList.Members)
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub Expand2ndLevelDistList(myDistListMembers As Outlook.AddressEntries)
'Get email addresses from the 2nd level/layer of the primary distribution list (sub distribution lists in the primary distribution list)

Dim myDistListMemberItem As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To myDistListMembers.Count
    Set myDistListMemberItem = myDistListMembers.Item(i)
    If myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olUser Then
        Debug.Print "Level 2" & vbTab & i & vbTab & myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    ElseIf myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olDistList Then
        Call Expand3rdLevelDistList(myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeDistributionList.Members)
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub Expand3rdLevelDistList(myDistListMembers As Outlook.AddressEntries)
'Get email addresses from the 3rd level/layer of the primary distribution list

Dim myDistListMemberItem As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To myDistListMembers.Count
    Set myDistListMemberItem = myDistListMembers.Item(i)
    If myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olUser Then
        Debug.Print "Level 3" & vbTab & i & vbTab & myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    ElseIf myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olDistList Then
        Call Expand4thLevelDistList(myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeDistributionList.Members)
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub Expand4thLevelDistList(myDistListMembers As Outlook.AddressEntries)
'Get email addresses from the 4th level/layer of the primary distribution list
Dim myDistListMemberItem As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To myDistListMembers.Count
    Set myDistListMemberItem = myDistListMembers.Item(i)
    If myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olUser Then
        Debug.Print "Level 4" & vbTab & i & vbTab & myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    ElseIf myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olDistList Then
        Call Expand5thLevelDistList(myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeDistributionList.Members)
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub Expand5thLevelDistList(myDistListMembers As Outlook.AddressEntries)
'Get email addresses from the 5th level/layer of the primary distribution list
Dim myDistListMemberItem As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To myDistListMembers.Count
    Set myDistListMemberItem = myDistListMembers.Item(i)
    If myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olUser Then
        Debug.Print "Level 4" & vbTab & i & vbTab & myDistListMemberItem.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    ElseIf myDistListMemberItem.DisplayType = olDistList Then
        MsgBox "Please contact developer for the 6th level of emails in the distribution list.", vbOKOnly
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```